# PDO and performance

Tags: php, performance, pdo, performance-testing

There is a large php application that uses the PDO api
(http://php.net/pdo) to store and retrieve information from one or more
databases. Over the software development lifetime of your application, you have found that a significant number of performance problems have been due to PDO API calls taking a long time.

- How would you determine how much time is being spent in each PDO API call? We are not interested in differentiating the amount DB execution time from the amount of time in each API call.
- How does your solution impact the maintainability of your application? Specifically, if a new framework is added to the application how would your solution time PDO calls in that framework?
- In what ways could your solution change the performance characteristics of your application?

Comment: The time that PDO takes to make a call is instant in comparison to network overhead and DB time. So the problems aren't caused by "PDO API calls" but by "performing database queries"

Comment: @zerkms, Have you measured the difference between query execution time and roundtrip time?

Comment: @Bill Karwin: was it to me? In either way, DB performance (and roundtrip) has nothing to do with DBAL used.

Comment: @zerkms Is it just me or it really sounds like a homework?

Comment: @Your Common Sense: It's you ;-)

Comment: sniff sniff... this **reeks** of homework.

Answer (score 0):

> How would you determine how much time is being spent in each PDO API call? We are not interested in differentiating the amount DB execution time from the amount of time in each API call.

I would inherit from `PDO` with my custom class and put watches there

> How does your solution impact the maintainability of your application? Specifically, if a new framework is added to the application how would your solution time PDO calls in that framework?

Everything that can work with PDO would work with the extension as well. LSP principle

> In what ways could your solution change the performance characteristics of your application?

Nope (excluding the minor overhead for storing profiling results, if you need it)

Comment: So are you suggesting to use the inherited classes instead of PDO? This might mean a major refactoring effort... My initial thought was just to put some logging to track how long it takes PDO calls to come back. What if anything is wrong with that approach?

Comment: @psychickita: "This might mean a major refactoring effort" --- that only means, that you have problems with dependency management in your code. In a well designed application the switch to another DBAL (with the same interface) would cost 1 line of code.